# How can I make an android game app configurable via a xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml, config

**What I want to do:**
I want to create a simple serious game for kids, where they drag and drop pictures (e.g. match the right shapes, circle to circle etc.), but the teachers should be able to define the game according to their wishes and put own images into the drawable folder of the uncompiled project. Then they run gradle and they get the desired apk file. That's basically the idea.

**Now let me explain a little bit further:**
The XML defines the game-app:
The game-app consists of 1-n "game worlds" (background image with some scenes on it, e.g. background the sea and as scenes ball playing kids, a sand castle, a boat...).
A "game world" consists of 1-n levels (the scenes on the background, e.g. ball playing kids).
A "level" consists of 1-n exercises (the actual game, e.g. there is a cicrle on the right side of the screen, a bucket on the left side of the screen, and some objects in the middle of the screen. The user has to drag and drop the correct object to the solution on the right side and all incorrect (unmatching) objetcs into the bucket on the left side.

The teachers write the XML-file, for example in this form:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<app>
    <world>
        <level>
            <exercise>
                <solution>ex1_sol</solution>
                <correct>ex1_2</correct>
                <res>
                    <img>ex1_sol</img>
                    <img>ex1_1</img>
                    <img>ex1_2</img>
                    <img>ex1_3</img>
                </res>
            </exercise>
        </level>
    </world>
</app>
```

The app should parse the XML. My idea is, that every Object (app, world, game, level) is stored in a list and for every object there will be some code. But I think this is a complicated approach and not very efficient.

**So here's my question:**
How can I achieve to build such a configurable game app? After long research I found hints pointing to gradle and build variants, but I have no idea how to do it this way or if it even fits my needs. Have you any idea how one can build a configurable android app in the described setting?

Comment: "The teachers write the XML-file" ... Computer Science Teachers? If not: forget it. Build a Teacher's Configuration GUI. In general, you wouldn't want the App to be built anew every time a teacher comes up with a new setup. You would then also need Devices to accept 3rd Party source Apps which is insecure (-er than Playstore-only).

Comment: Generally i guess you are on the right way with XML, but letting the teacher edit this files or even compiling a android project i guess it's bad usability. You could make it static at the beginning, like put those xml files into an **asset** folder and dynamically read all xml files from there. Later implement a flexible editor into the app or a web based editor.